# A simple model for binding strings or other non list/tree types to qt widgets(mvvm style)

Tags: qt, mvvm, garbage-collection, pyqt, signals-slots

My last major experience with desktop gui programming was using c#/wpf in a mvvm fashion.  I added an observable collection that you didn't have to change on the main thread(it was implemented by forwarding calls to an instance of the normal observable collection using locking and running on the gui thread when appropriate). Instead of gui event handlers where you play around with navigating the file tree I had methods in the viewmodel which only affected the viewmodel. I really like the fact that you could mostly contain the gui code with itself and that the view model code was mostly straightforward avoiding dealing with the view except by updating state and sending change events.

I'm building a small self contained(no dependencies if possible) application using pyqt 4.6(so I don't think qml is available, also qtwebkit seems to be a in a different package that isn't installed on these boxes). I'm interested in trying to separate the data from the ui in a sort of mvvm fashion.

I can use qt model/views (setModel) for the list and tree models but I'm not sure what to do for strings/ints/other values. The application will probably be fairly static(no disappearing gui elements in the middle) but if it gets more complicated(say with popup windows) I'd like it not to crash or memory usage to explode due to memory leaks. I'm a bit uncertain about how the python gc interacts with signals/slots and qt's parent/child memory cleanup.

The application I'm writing is small so a smaller self contained solution(that might not be as universal/featureful) or a small bsd/mit library I can extract/copy code from would be preferred.

Here is what I have so far, although as stated I'm a bit uncertain it's bug free.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
from __future__ import print_function
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
from time import sleep

def identity_function(x):
    return x


def data_bind(model_get_prop, model_set_prop,
              get_widget_prop, set_widget_prop,
              model_prop_changed, window_prop_changed,
              transform_func=identity_function,
              transform_back_func=identity_function):
    set_widget_prop(transform_func(model_get_prop()))

    def set_m():
        if model_get_prop() != get_widget_prop():
            model_set_prop(transform_back_func(get_widget_prop()))
    window_prop_changed.connect(set_m)

    def set_w_prop():
        if get_widget_prop() != model_get_prop():
            set_widget_prop(transform_func(model_get_prop()))
    model_prop_changed.connect(set_w_prop)

class ValueModel(QtCore.QObject):
    model_changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, value):
        super(ValueModel, self).__init__()
        self.__value = value
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.__value
    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        if self.__value != value:
            self.__value = value
            self.model_changed.emit()


def gui_main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    s_model = ValueModel("yo")

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

    t = QtGui.QTextEdit()
    vbox.addWidget(t)
    t2 = QtGui.QTextEdit()
    vbox.addWidget(t2)
    w.setLayout(vbox)
    data_bind(lambda: s_model.value, lambda v: setattr(s_model, 'value', v), t.toPlainText, t.setPlainText, s_model.model_changed, t.textChanged)
    data_bind(lambda: s_model.value, lambda v: setattr(s_model, 'value', v), t2.toPlainText, t2.setPlainText, s_model.model_changed, t2.textChanged)

    l1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    l2 = QtGui.QLineEdit()

    lm1 = ValueModel(2)
    lm2 = ValueModel(1)

    vbox.addWidget(l1)
    vbox.addWidget(l2)

    lm1.model_changed.connect(lambda: print("l1 + l2 is " + str(lm1.value+lm2.value)))
    lm2.model_changed.connect(lambda: print("l1 + l2 is " + str(lm1.value+lm2.value)))
    data_bind(lambda: lm1.value, lambda v: setattr(lm1, 'value', v), l1.text, l1.setText, lm1.model_changed, l1.textChanged, str, int)
    data_bind(lambda: lm2.value, lambda v: setattr(lm2, 'value', v), l2.text, l2.setText, lm2.model_changed, l2.textChanged, str, int)

    w.show()
    t.setText("a")
    print(s_model.value)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

gui_main()
```

Comment: There are several unfinished sentences in this question. What are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is `QDataWidgetMapper`.

In short, it allows you to map the value of a column of a model to the displayed property of a widget (like a label or a lineedit). If you update the value in either the widget or the model, the other will be updated.

You can also step through the rows of the model which will update all the mapped widgets to the contents of the next row in the model (this is probably more than you need, so you'd just have one row in the model).

See the Qt Documentation for more details: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatawidgetmapper.html